# How not to reload component when page is reloading Angular

Tags: javascript, angular

I need to save a lot of data when user reloads a page. I know, that I can use localstorage, but it will be very difficult for me, because I have really lot of data. So, is it possible not to reload component or page, when user reloads page?

Comment: try using indexedDB instead of localstorage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`localStorage` is not the only option to keep data. `Indexed DB` might help you.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API

As a disadvantage, it's kinda low-level and verbose. You can search npm packages for Angular. Try [this one](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-indexed-db)

Comment: I know how to use localstorage, my question is is it possible not to refresh data from my component.

Comment: It doesn't matter, whether it is Angular, React or vanilla JS. On page reload, your browser downloads SAME script file and executes code over and over. Where do you see a hole to conceal your data, if your file hasn't changed?
Use the power of your server or something that your browser can offer